# Maven Site - Multi Module Project - Grouping of Submodules

Tags: maven, multi-module, maven-site-plugin

I am generating a site using the maven site plugin (version 3.4).
My project(-pom) structure is as follows:

```
Root
  +--Sub1
  +--Sub2
  +--Sub3
       +--SubSub1
       +--SubSub2
```

Unfortunately in the "Root" about site, where the modules are listed, also the SubSub modules are listed, whereas the folder structure in the staging directory correctly represents the project structure.

Is there a solution for this? Basically I do not want to show the SubSub modules in the root site about page.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can place the (sub)modules where you want. You just have to specify the relative paths in the modules tag (for parents), and in the parent tag (for modules).

Comment: In my root pom I already specifed the Submodules using <modules><module>Sub1</module><module>Sub2</module><module>Sub3</module></modules>, furthermore my Sub3 module contains <modules><module>SubSub1</module><module>SubSub2</module></modules>, still, in the root about site, the sub modules of "Sub3" are shown (SubSub1, SubSub2)

Comment: I wrote **relative paths**, as in ../sub-in-parent-dir or /child-dir/sub-child-dir. If you don't specify the relative paths to the desired directories, the submodules are assumed to be contained in their parent.

Comment: Just saw it: I don't think you can nest module tags. You have to define subsub1 in sub3.